# How do I write a DateTime to the console with milliseconds included

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact("18/03/201115:16:57.487",
                                            "dd/MM/yyyyHH:mm:ss.fff", 
                                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        Console.WriteLine("Other Output:" + time);
    }
}
```

The line being written to the console does **not** include the milliseconds. How do I fix that?

Comment: This code return output up to seconds, how to get milliseconds

Comment: @Manil - almost certainly, anywhere where you're encountering something where milliseconds are missing, it's because you've allowed your `DateTime` value to be *converted* to a `string` (and possibly back again). Stop allowing these conversions from happening, keep everything in good, solid types (`DateTime` in C#, `datetime2` in SQL and as the parameter type) (Or the column is defined as `datetime2(0)`, but then there's no mystery there)

Comment: How do I write dates to the console with milliseconds included?

Comment: I have updated your question to reflect your actual problem. Lars has provided the answer below. Or read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-display-milliseconds-in-date-and-time-values . I want to be 100% clear here though - **do not use this technique to send dates to SQL Server**.

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing the string correctly, including the milliseconds. You can verify this, by setting a breakpoint in your code, and inspect the value of `time` after parsing.

[image: Screenshot, debugging the code showing the milliseconds have been parsed correctly.]

The reason you are not seeing the milliseconds, is because you aren't specifying the format when printing it in the console. To do this, use the same format you used to parse the string:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string customFormat = "dd/MM/yyyyHH:mm:ss.fff";

    DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact("18/03/201115:16:57.487", customFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    Console.WriteLine("Other Output:" + time.ToString(customFormat));
}
```

Now that the `DateTime` has been parsed, you can save it to your database.

Comment: If we convert to string and apply format is working. Is  it possible to insert the datetime with milliseconds, using this property "public DateTime? CreateDate {get;set;}"
Eg:public DateTime? CreateDate {get;set;}
      DateTime="18/03/201115:16:57.487"; like this